# Why is this question being downvoted heavily?

Tags: discussion, voting, specific-question, self-answer

I made the [idle-supermarket-tycoon](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idle-supermarket-tycoon) tag, because I want to talk about it with some questions of it.

I asked this question: [What are the descriptions of each item?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/383231), and I gained a downvote, but what's interesting is that the question and every answer I left on it have a score of -1. Nothing bad, but thanks to the votes, it could potentially lead to an answer ban if there are more downvotes on it.

What should I do about this? Is there a way to improve this post?

Comment: The first thing is to not post multiple answers. Sure it'll make for one long answer, but posting multiple answers can be seen as rep-farming

Comment: One of the downvote reasons is that the post is "not useful". What is the purpose of asking that question? What use does it serve? Because it looks to me like you're asking for a giant list of in-game flavor text.

Comment: I've gone ahead and combined the answers into one. As @Unionhawk explains - answers should be one 'complete' answer to the question. Posting multiple partial answers (one for each 'section') is not a great fit for our site. Yeah, this means we lose the functionality to link directly to 'sections' (a [long-requested feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89314/179041) for the SE engine), but writing complete answers is how the Q&A format should work.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Yum, flavor text!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not currently answer banned, and while I don't know the exact formula for an answer ban, a skim of your answers list leads me to believe that you are not actually at risk of an answer ban, so I wouldn't worry there. Obviously I can only eyeball this, but you have a good amount of positively or neutrally received answers, so a handful of negatively received answers aren't going to outweigh that soon.

This is really more of a [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) issue, so let's dive into that. The way you have your question and self-answers set up is fairly problematic for the format. In general, posting multiple answers on one question is discouraged. The system will even prompt you to suggest that you edit your existing answer instead if you try to post a second answer. The site operates by seeking a best answer from experts both by soliciting expert answers, but also expert votes. The best answers are brought to the top by upvotes. This doesn't really work with multiple partial answers. One high-quality complete answer is much better than several incomplete answers.

While I don't personally think the question is very useful, the answer would be much, much better if it wasn't split in 5.

Comment: Alternatively, it could be 5 questions, each with one answer.

Comment: @murgatroid99 maybe, but i think it would be super redundant for that to be separate questions, i wouldnt go that route for things that could be general/similar to this if ur purely answering your own question and plan to give the other info anyway